# Sigma-additive measure on algebra of sets

Tags: measure-theory

Most of the time, $\sigma$-additive functions are defined on $\sigma$-algebras of sets.

Is it possible to define a $\sigma$-additive function on an algebra of sets?

If so, what is the theory/technique to do it?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Restrict your favourite measure to your favourite sub-algebra of its domain ...

Comment: The definition is then just that $\mu(A) = \sum_n \mu(A_n)$ has to hold if $A = \biguplus_n A_n$ with $A_n \in \mathcal{A}$ and $A \in \mathcal{A}$ (this is part of the prerequisite now) for the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ you are considering. Using Caratheodory's extension theorem, one can show that one can always extend $\mu$ to a measure on $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$, so that (apart from proving/using that theorem), there is not much of a point in considering such $\sigma$-additive functions on algebras.